# Stored Procedure not inserting via C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, insert

My stored procedure works fine in my SQL EXEC query. It inserts into my DB but does not when I call it from C# though it does not throw an error. What is happening.

My C# Code:

```
        con.Open();
        transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertIndent", con, transaction);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@IP_No", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
        cmd.Parameters["@IP_No"].Value = indent.IP_No;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Stat", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1);
        cmd.Parameters["@Stat"].Value = indent.Status;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reference_No", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
        cmd.Parameters["@Reference_No"].Value = indent.Reference_No;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Remarks", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
        cmd.Parameters["@Remarks"].Value = indent.Remarks;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Update_Time", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cmd.Parameters["@Update_Time"].Value = indent.Update_Time;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_Id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
        cmd.Parameters["@User_Id"].Value = indent.User_Id;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Log_Id", SqlDbType.BigInt);
        cmd.Parameters["@Log_Id"].Value = indent.Log_Id;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Shift_Id", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@Shift_Id"].Value = indent.Shift_Id;

        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
        log.Debug("connection.cs : inside addNewIndent,for IpNo " + indent.IP_No);
        con.Close();
```

My values while Tracing
[image: The values]

My Stored Procedure:

```
[InsertIndent]
(
@IP_No varchar(15),        
@Stat varchar(1),      
@Reference_No varchar(15),
@Remarks varchar(30),   
@Update_Time DATETIME,
@User_Id varchar(15),
@Log_Id bigint,
@Shift_Id int
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Indent_No varchar(20)
set @Indent_No= (SELECT TOP 1 In_Id from Id_Generation WITH(NOLOCK))

INSERT INTO IP_Indent(IP_No,Indent_No,Status,Reference_No,Remarks,User_Id,Log_Id,Shift_Id,Update_Time)
VALUES(@IP_No,@Indent_No,@Stat,@Reference_No,@Remarks,@User_Id,@Log_Id,@Shift_Id,@Update_Time)

Update Id_Generation set In_Id=In_Id+1;

END
```

Comment: Just as an aside, your code would be simpler if you set each parameter value in the same statement that you add it, e.g. `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Shift_Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = indent.Shift_Id;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've started a transaction, you'll also need to [commit it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before you close the connection, otherwise the change will be rolled back.

On another note, why not use an IDENTITY for that `Id_Generation` counter column? As it stands, if 2 concurrent callers call your proc, they could both wind up with the same value of `Id_Generation`.

Also, note that `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` are both `Disposable` - e.g. wrapping both in a `using` statement will ensure that resources are released ASAP.

Comment: What do you mean by IDENTITY?

Comment: I mean, change the column from `INT` to `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` as per [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx). This way, you can leave Sql Server to generate the incrementing counter without having to worry about concurrency issues. Fetch the assigned value with `SCOPE_IDENTTY()` in your proc.

Comment: That was amazing. Thanks for the timely help. :)